# System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback related startup crash

Tags: multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android, threadpool

In my application, running on a LG G3 D855, I get this error on when starting up, it happens usually when my application has not been started in a while, always restarting it after it crashes works fine:

```
E/linker  ( 2105): readlink('/proc/self/fd/28') failed: Permission denied [fd=28]
E/linker  ( 2105): warning: unable to get realpath for the library "/vendor/lib/egl/eglsubAndroid.so". Will use given name.
E/mono    ( 2105): 
E/mono    ( 2105): Unhandled Exception:
E/mono    ( 2105): System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
E/mono    ( 2105):   at Dictionary.Fragments.SearchFragment+<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<PerformSearch>b__0 (System.Object x) [0x00050] in <88db5ed5788f4131a4894bb5620511e9>:0 
E/mono    ( 2105):   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context (System.Object state) [0x0000e] in <8552b98493c447d5a7a1f07bdaff39bb>:0 
E/mono    ( 2105):   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x0008d] in <8552b98493c447d5a7a1f07bdaff39bb>:0 
E/mono    ( 2105):   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run (System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, System.Object state, System.Boolean preserveSyncCtx) [0x00000] in <8552b98493c447d5a7a1f07bdaff39bb>:0 
E/mono    ( 2105):   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem () [0x0002a] in <8552b98493c447d5a7a1f07bdaff39bb>:0 
E/mono    ( 2105):   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch () [0x00096] in <8552b98493c447d5a7a1f07bdaff39bb>:0 
E/mono    ( 2105):   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback () [0x00000] in <8552b98493c447d5a7a1f07bdaff39bb>:0
```

This is the code it fails on:

```
private void PerformSearch(string input) {
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( x => {
    if ( _tranService == null )
      _tranService = new TranslationService();

    var translations = _tranService.Translate( input );
    _transAdapter.Update( translations );
    Activity.RunOnUiThread( () => _transAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged() );
  } );
}
```

Please let me know what this is, its annoying me very much. Its also happening in another app I am making which uses the same kind of `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` block.

My installation:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update
>   3 Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.01586
>
> Installed Version: Professional
>
> Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2015
>   00322-40000-00000-AA309 Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications
>   2015
>
> Visual Basic 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA309 Microsoft Visual Basic
>   2015
>
> Visual C# 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA309 Microsoft Visual C# 2015
>
> Visual C++ 2015   00322-40000-00000-AA309 Microsoft Visual C++ 2015
>
> Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   7.17.00119.9
>   Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio
>
> ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1   14.1.21111.0 ASP.NET and Web Tools
>   2015.1
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563
>
> ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0 For additional
>   information, visit http://www.asp.net/
>
> Azure App Service Tools v2.8.1   14.0.11123.0 Azure App Service Tools
>   v2.8.1
>
> Command Bus, Event Stream and Async Manager   Merq Provides
>   ICommandBus, IEventStream and IAsyncManager MEF services for loosely
>   coupled Visual Studio extension components communication and
>   integration.
>
> Common Azure Tools   1.8 Provides common services for use by Azure
>   Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.
>
> Indent Guides   15 Indent Guides
>
> Adds visual guides at each indentation level.
>
> JavaScript Language Service   2.0 JavaScript Language Service
>
> JavaScript Project System   2.0 JavaScript Project System
>
> JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 2016.2.2    Build 106.0.20160913.91321
>   JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate package for Microsoft Visual Studio. For
>   more information about ReSharper Ultimate, visit
>   http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper. Copyright © 2017 JetBrains, Inc.
>
> Microsoft .NET Core Tools (Preview 2)   14.1.21111.0 Microsoft .NET
>   Core Tools (Preview 2)
>
> Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4 Microsoft Azure Mobile
>   Services Tools
>
> NuGet Package Manager   3.5.0 NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio.
>   For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.
>
> PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2 Microsoft Visual Studio
>   extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive
>   Analytics product.
>
> SQL Server Analysis Services   13.0.1605.88 Microsoft SQL Server
>   Analysis Services Designer  Version 13.0.1605.88
>
> SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60629.0 Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools
>
> SQL Server Integration Services    Microsoft SQL Server Integration
>   Services Designer Version 13.0.1601.5
>
> SQL Server Reporting Services   13.0.1605.88 Microsoft SQL Server
>   Reporting Services Designers  Version 13.0.1605.88
>
> TypeScript   1.8.36.0 TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
>
> Visual Studio Tools for Unity   2.8.0.0 Visual Studio Tools for Unity
>
> Windows Installer XML Toolset   3.10.2.2516 Windows Installer XML
>   Toolset version 3.10.2.2516 Copyright (c) Outercurve Foundation. All
>   rights reserved.
>
> Xamarin   4.2.2.11 (00fa5cc) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.Android   7.0.2.42 (501e63c) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.Android.
>
> Xamarin.iOS   10.3.1.8 (7beaef4) Visual Studio extension to enable
>   development for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: Can you step through the code in that method to try to see what object is null? My first thought would be _transAdapter as you are not doing a null check on it. Perhaps somehow _transAdapter is being disposed and is not recreated when resuming the app?

Comment: @jgoldberger problem is, it happens on the actual device on startup, intermittently, I cannot debug it.

Comment: Perhaps try doing a null check on _transAdapter just to see if that might be the issue: `_transAdapter?.Update( translations ); ` or `if (_transAdapter != null) _transAdapter.Update( translations );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in both my apps by not using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` and instead using TPL, `Task.Factory.StartNew()` to do the same thing. I did not find out why the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` failed, and Xamarin did not log a response to my bug report.